# Enum as singleton or fully functional class

Tags: java, enum

Joshua Bloch claims that

> "a single-element enumeration type is the best way to implement a
>   singleton"

Why? I totally disagree with this statement because enumeration is data type with some type-safe constants, like `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `WEST`, `EAST`. I think that stable singleton can be creating using class with adding some boiler plate code. Using enumeration as fully-functional object seems misleading to me. Is it really a good approach to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This is why:

> This approach is functionally equivalent to the public field approach,
>   except that it is more concise, provides the serialization machinery
>   for free, and provides an ironclad guarantee against multiple
>   instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or
>   reflection attacks. While this approach has yet to be widely adopted,
>   a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton.

(from http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3)

Have you not read this, or are you disagreeing with Bloch's reasoning?

Comment: I disagree with Bloch on this one, because enumerations purpose is NOT the same as the classes purpose - it should be used to store enumerated values not act like a fully functional class.

Comment: @Heisenberg what's wrong with enumerated values encapsulating behaviour in form of methods? In a sense, a singleton _is_ actually an enumerated value. The one and only value of its type.

Comment: I don't think it should be doing some operations on data.

Comment: Here are some legit operations that I have used in enums: decoding legacy enum values (received by outdated remote clients) that I've since refactored away; providing useful coarser flags than the enum itself does ("Is this role an admin role?"); evaluation methods for an enum representing arithmetic operations; associating I18N text keys with menu options... All of these should go into the `enum` rather than an external helper class, by the principles of good factoring. Java would be a worse language if `enum`s didn't support methods.

Comment: @Heisenberg "...enumerations purpose is NOT the same as the classes purpose" It doesn't matter what you think their purpose is; that's subjective. What isn't subjective is that you can use them as singletons, all the bookkeeping is done for you automatically, and it works at least as well as a thorough and complete hand-rolled implementation. There's no good reason to try to reimplement it yourself and risk screwing it up. Besides, every enum is a class (`enum Foo` == `class Foo extends Enum<Foo>`) so it's a moot point.

Comment: @Heisenberg It doesn't matter what `enum`'s original purpose was. This is something that was found afterwards: that it's the safest way to write singletons. All other ways are error-prone or bugged in subtle ways.